# asp.net application requests stuck in "SendResponse" state

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, response

Im troubleshooting some application performance issues and have noticed that when i look in IIS 7 (under worker processes), the long running requests are stuck in "SendResponse" in the pipeline.

Some of these requests can be in that state for 200+ seconds.

I'm not sure if this questions is best asked here or in serverfault, but figured I would ask here since I'm guessing its an application issue instead of a server issue.

Anyways, has anyone seen this before, and know what might be causing it?  I'm running asp.net 3.5 32 bit on a 64 bit machine in classic mode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There might be IIS configuration issue. Have you created 32 bit worker process on your 64 bit machine.

Comment: Yes - the w3wp.exe is running in 32.  I mean - the servers handle a good amount of traffic - its just that I see these requests that are very long running in that state.  I'm just not clear whats actually happening on the server when that happens.  Has the page finished processing and is pushing the response?

Comment: I'm having this issue to, very puzzling.